# Sorting an huge array of integers each represented by 10 bits

Tags: arrays, sorting, counting-sort

For a problem like this -how to sort an array of integers where each integer is represented by 10 bit?
I believe we can use counting sort.But if I slightly tweak the problem to each item being a combination of an integer and a string, and the question asks the array to be sorted based on the integer value,how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use a bin sort like counting sort.  There will still be 1024 bins, but rather than holding the count, each bin holds a list of the strings with the corresponding integer key.

You can sort the strings in each bin separately if that is required.  For this a comparison sort like quicksort will be best.